# Return a list of race positions without the values

Tags: python, lambda, sorting

So basically I am trying to figure out a way I can return a list of racers finishing positions without returning the values they had as well. The following is the information I have to use:

```
{'Dennis': 90.0, 'Alice': 100.0, 'Bob': 101.4389222493041, 'Eva': 94.18226076274071, 'Clare': 111.52090179040226}
```

and I need to return the following:

```
['Clare', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Eva', 'Dennis']
```

So basically it sorts there position in descending order. Notice that the actually scores are not returning. I know I need to use "sorted and a lambda function for the dictionary but I can't quite figure out how it will work.

```
def findresult(randomscore):
    finalscore = sorted(randomscore, key=lambda x: x)
    return(finalscore)
```

That's what I feel is correct at the moment, I just don't understand how to configure it to sort them by score, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need  `sorted` using `dict.get`  as the sort `key`  with `reverse=True` to sort from highest value to lowest,

```
d = {'Dennis': 90.0, 'Alice': 100.0, 'Bob': 101.4389222493041, 'Eva': 94.18226076274071, 'Clare': 111.52090179040226}

print(sorted(d,key=d.get,reverse=True))
['Clare', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Eva', 'Dennis']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderdirct, to order your directionayr

```
d = {'Dennis': 90.0, 'Alice': 100.0, 'Bob': 101.4389222493041, 'Eva': 94.18226076274071, 'Clare': 111.52090179040226}

from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])))

print(od)
print([k for k in od])
```

Prints:

```
    OrderedDict([('Clare', 111.52090179040226), ('Bob', 101.4389222493041), ('Alice', 100.0), ('Eva', 94.18226076274071), ('Dennis', 90.0)])


   ['Clare', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Eva', 'Dennis']
```